# TFSConfig Import vs database copy with TFS Upgrade Wizard for migration

Tags: tfs-migration

I'm planning a hardware migration upgrade from TFS 2008 to TFS 2012 and I'm encountering two different paths.

The [ALM Rangers TFS Upgrade Guide](http://vsarupgradeguide.codeplex.com/releases) has a path involving setting up TFS 2012 on the new servers and then running the TFSConfig Import command to get the old projects into the new TFS.

On the other hand, [the official Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd631902(v=vs.110).aspx) and a few other have procedures that involve installing TFS 2012 on the new servers, copying the TFS tables to the new TFS 2012 DB location, then running the TFS 2012 Upgrade Wizard to handle converting the TFS 2008 tables to TFS 2012.

Which is the safest path with the least pitfalls, or are they roughly equivalent?

I do plan on migrating and upgrading Sharepoint Foundation as well, if that has any impact.

Answer (score 1):

You should go for the upgrade wizard. 
Unfortunately the wording in the upgrade guide wasn't that clear but there is a paragraph that details when to use what.
"The Import command is not intended to be a substitute or a replacement for the upgrade wizard for TFS 2012. The primary use for this command is to aggregate multiple deployments of previous versions of TFS into a deployment of TFS 2012."

Comment: I need to update my OP as indeed the import command failed for reasons unknown to me and wasted good amounts of my time between repairing the original environment after the failure and getting things set up for the import in the first place.  I had other problems in the upgrade relating to the SQL server being 2005 and I have a hunch that might be what caused TFSConfig Import to fail.

Comment: Make sure you look at the SoftWare requirements in the upgrade guide or on this link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578592.aspx If you are replacing the hardware make sure that you also upgrade to the latest software to have an easier route onwards after this upgrade